# I couldn't open the 'about.html' when using return render in views.py

Tags: python, django

Sorry that I am new in Django, as I am creating a website and try to use generic way, but when I use the way for return render, it can't open the related html file(about.html), someone help?
views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.
class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')[:4]
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about')
]
```

Comment: what do you mean "it can't open the related html file"? Do you get an error? If so, please copy&paste the error trace in your question. What are you doing exactly that causes it? Which url are you for example entering in your browser?

Comment: Can you show the project file system? So we can check the `about.html` file is in the app in the templates directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your urls.py are not setup correctly: `path('<slug:slug>/',...)` matches also the url "/about/" so it will launch the post_detail view with slug="about".

You need to change the order of your urls from most specific to least specific (so "about" before "post_detail"). Better, change your urls that relate to posts to contain the "posts" word, this is also better practice:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('posts/', views.PostList.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('posts/<slug:slug>', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about')
]
```

Comment: thanks, everything is fine after I changed the order of it,  I still using ' ' for 'index' as I need the homepage for it.